# Linq compare XML Values

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I cannot believe it is so difficult to just compare two XML columns using linq to see if they are equal.  This only happens in my system once in a blue moon, but I want to account for it when it does.

I have tried a straight comparison, and attempted the comparison with the .ToString() method.  Both the attempts I made threw a useless error...

My original linq statement:

```
from al in ActivityLogs
join a in Activities on al.ActivityId equals a.ActivityId
join dva in AllDVAudits on al.ActivityLogId equals dva.ActivityLogId
where al.ProfileId == ProfileID
```

I have tried adding this:

```
Where al.ProfileId == ProfileID 
  && al.OldData != al.NewData
```

And this

```
Where al.ProfileId == ProfileID    
 && al.OldData.ToString() != al.NewData.ToString()
```

**UPDATE**:  I also thought to myself "*Screw it, I will just bring back the XML and manipulate it ( compare it ) in C#*".  I hate to have to bring the XML back from my data server just to see if they are equal, but at least I can compare the values at this point.

**Is there a way to just determine if the two XML columns are equal using linq?**

**Any** insight greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to compare in sql ?

Comment: I would really like to use linq if at all possible, I can just cast it to a varchar using sql easy enough.

Comment: BTW, how the heck does an question get up voted here?  :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution 1 : 
I you do Linq SQL, may be you can create a computed column is SQL Server with cast your XML column into varchar(2000) by example and use this column into your linq

Solution 2 :
Create a view with convert column into varchar and use into Linq

Solution 3 :
Create a view with your complete query and linq into this view

Solution 4 (i dont kwo if its work) :

```
    var all = from bm in context.MYTABLEs
              select new { name = bm.SPP_USER_ID, xml = (string)bm.SPP_BOOKMARKS_XML };

    var docs = from x in all
               select XDocument.Parse(x.xml);

    var href = from h in docs
               select h.Descendants("href");
```

Comment: How would I modify my original linq statement in my answer for that?  Do you have a sample or reference I could view?

Comment: Yes sir, I believe that is correct.  We are using EF4 with an EF6 wrapper available.

Comment: In my solution1 i propose to create into your database a computed column = to cast(columnxml as varchar(2000)) , refresh your model EF and use this computed columns for your linq

Comment: I may give this a shot at some point, for now I am just going to bring it back and compare it in C#.